# How to place div in second row directly under div in first row with same column size but blocked by the height of another column in first row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, dom

Sorry if the title is confusing. I have included a screenshot of my issue to make it more clear.

[image]

Essentially, I want the green-bordered div to be directly underneath the red-bordered div without the blue-bordered div interfering.

Here is my HTML code (I am using Bootstrap v3.3.7)

```
<div class="container appParent">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6" id="song-view">
            <app-selected-song-view></app-selected-song-view>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" id="songs-added">
            <app-songs-added></app-songs-added>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6" id="playlist-form">
            <app-playlist-form></app-playlist-form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS is only putting the borders around the div. Everything else is bootstrap.

```
#song-view{
    border: 2px solid red;
}
#songs-added{
    border: 2px solid blue;    
}
#playlist-form{
    border: 2px solid green;    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, use `pull-right`, and keep all of the `col-` in a single `row`.

```
<div class="container appParent">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6" id="song-view">
            <app-selected-song-view></app-selected-song-view>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 pull-right col-xs-12" id="songs-added">
            <app-songs-added></app-songs-added>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" id="playlist-form">
            <app-playlist-form></app-playlist-form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/189ofQG5Sj

Answer (score 1):

You can re-arrange your HTML.

```css
#song-view {
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#songs-added {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  height: 150px;
}

#playlist-form {
  border: 2px solid green;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container appParent">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div id="song-view">
        <app-selected-song-view></app-selected-song-view>
      </div>
      <div id="playlist-form">
        <app-playlist-form></app-playlist-form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div id="songs-added">
        <app-songs-added></app-songs-added>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use min-heights and surround the containers and rows with a div for extra styling. You can check this example I quickly made: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshuaNewell/a2fyz5os/)

```
<div class="song-list">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-6" id="song-view">
               Song View
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6" id="songs-added">
               Songs Added
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>

<div class="playlist">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-6" id="playlist-form">
                Playlist Form
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.song-list #song-view {
  border:1px solid blue;
  min-height:300px;
}
.song-list #songs-added {
  border:1px solid red;
  min-height:500px;
}

.playlist #playlist-form {
  border:1px solid green;
}
```

Comment: Not sure how this solves his issue? Your jsfiddle example pose the same issue as what he is having/explained. @Michael Coker or ZimSystem provided the correct answer to his issue.

Comment: @12seconds ah yeah! Sorry. I misread it and got a different interpretation from the image my mistake.